# How to extract specific text inside an HTML tag with Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have an HTML tag like this:

```
<ul class="clearfix">
  "<li><span class="bold-title">Starts:</span> October 2013</li>"
</ul>
```

I want to extract "October 2013".
My code is:

```
start_date = articl.find('ul', class_='clearfix').find('li').text.strip()
```

...which extracts "Starts: October 2013".

How is it possible to take only the date?

Comment: Is it sure that there are ``"`` in front of and at the end of the line ``<li>.....</li>`` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a regex:

```
import re

ss = '''
<ul class="clearfix">
  <li><span class="bold-title">Starts:</span> October 2013</li>"
</ul>

blah blah

<ul class="clearfix">
  <li><<a href="/derives/certificats/"> November 2014     </li>"
</ul>
   '''

regx = re.compile('<ul +class="clearfix">.+?'
                  '<li>.*? *([^<>]+?) *</li>',
                  re.DOTALL)

print regx.findall(ss)

# prints ['October 2013', 'November 2014']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.contents`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children), which returns a list:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> html = (stuff above)
>>> soup = BS(html)
>>> print soup.find('li').contents[1].strip()
October 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hold = li.text
for eachTag in li.findAll():
    hold = hold.replace(eachTag.text,'')
```